# ImportError: cannot import name 'find_objects' why?

Tags: python, importerror, moviepy, modulenotfounderror

*when import find_objects from moviepy.video.tools.segmenting
i get in the result *
ImportError: cannot import name 'find_objects' from 'moviepy.video.tools.segmenting'
[when follow documentation](https://moviepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/moving_letters.html)

1. first i check if method is found by dir()
2. get findObjects in the result

**my problem solved**
ImportError: cannot import name 'find_objects'
from moviepy.video.tools.segmenting import findObjects

then replace find_objects by findObjects

Answer (score 0):

my problem solved ImportError: cannot import name 'find_objects' from moviepy.video.tools.segmenting import findObjects

then replace find_objects by findObjects